# MlFlow: Can't find runs using api

Tags: python, mlflow

I try get list of runs, but get empty list.

There are my runs:

[image]

But if I try get it using API:
I expect([by API](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#get-experiment)) that I also watch "runs", but watch "experiment" only

```
http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get?experiment_id=0
```

[image]

I read in doc, that "This field is deprecated. Please use the “Search Runs” API to fetch runs within an experiment.", Ok, I try “Search Runs”

[image]

Nothing again.

But I try get run by id(from ui):

[image]

I need get list of run ids by experiment id. How can I do it?

Comment: what version of MLflow?

Comment: @AlexOtt, latest

Comment: @Vetedde, did you find a solution for this? Facing this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

experiment_ids seems to expect an array, but you are not passing it an array